# How to add 'font color' option to Buedit

Tags: 7

I have used other text editors but BUEdit is my text editor of choice: lightweight and robust.

However, what I lack in its buttons is a function to enable users to colorize (and hence beautify) their texts. I'd be grateful to know how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enrich Bueditor by adding buttons to it. You can find some very well written documentation about how to add buttons to the editor [in the official bueditor page](http://ufku.com/drupal/bueditor/buttons).

After you have learned how to create buttons, you can use one of the already implemented buttons for text color. [You can find a demo and the actual button code here](http://ufku.com/drupal/bueditor/contributions/text-color).

The steps that I followed in a clean Drupal 7 installation:

1. Installed Bueditor
2. Navigated to Configuration - Content Authoring - Bueditor
3. Selected a random editor (e.g. Default) and hit "Edit"
4. Copied the 2 files from the second link in the library folder inside
   modules/bueditor
5. Added the following lines in "Editor specific library files":

   %BUEDITOR/library/bue.style.js

   %BUEDITOR/library/bue.colorbox.css
6. I went to the bottom of the page, above the "Save Configuration" button and in the blank button I added a title (i.e. Color), in the "Content" field I added the code from the second link (the code that is marked as: "Button code" (simple copy and paste)
7. In the place of the icon I just wrote: Color
8. Now just hit: "Save configuration" and go to the bottom of the page and check in the demo editor how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.I read the docs but still not sure how to implement the codes. I put the bue.style.js in BUEDIT's new button content and the bue.colorbox.css in my themes's style.css. Now the button and its color palette appear in the editor but clicking on colors has not colorizing effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the demo in the second link that I mentioned? You do not actually see the colorizing effect in the editor, but the corresponding html tag is added (e.g. <span style="color: #c09;">My text</span>). When you add the color in your editor, does it add the html? Or it does not do anything?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I mean, no tags has been added. Clicking on the palette just gets me to top of the page.

Comment: I'm editing my post above with the steps that I followed in order for it to work for me (tested it in a sample installation and work absolutely perfectly).